# Видео гайд не помог

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я смотрел видео гайд о том, как создать свою хоррор игру. Дело дошло до создания монстра, этот момент был на 10:37. Я делал объекты статичными, сделал монстру навигационную сетку, скопировал скрипт из видео, но вместо того чтобы идти за мной, монстр улетает вдаль.
Видео:
https://youtu.be/44qnn7TDqlI?si=VN4ZKDnEXxkV5VHl
Скрипт:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AI_Ray : MonoBehaviour {

```
private Transform Player;
private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent NMA;



void Start () {
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    NMA = (UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent)this.GetComponent("NavMeshAgent");
}


void Update () {
    NMA.SetDestination(Player.position);



}
```

}